# Can you open a question with bounty for a known bug in a popular library?

Tags: discussion

Assume that a popular framework or library has an open and active bug reported on GitHub. Can I open a Stack Overflow question for it and can I set a bounty on it?

What about if I ask for a work-around vs the actual bug fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Do you mean asking for someone to actually fix the bug in the library and setting a bounty on that?

Comment: @Keiwan Yes, and if the answer is no, then can I ask for a workaround instead?

Comment: "Is there a workaround for this?" is a valid question. "Can someone fix this?" is not, even if the solution is the same.

Comment: @approxiblue that's what I was wondering, thanks